# Why it is necessary to initialize a varriable before performing any assignment to it in C?

Tags: c, windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int sale;
    float comm = 0;
    
    printf("enter the sale amount: ");
    scanf("%d",&sale);
    
    if (sale < 10000) { 
    comm = 0; 
    }
    else if (sale >= 10000 && sale < 15000){
        comm = sale * 0.05;
    } else if (sale >= 15000 && sale < 25000) {
        comm = 0.1 * sale;
    } else if(sale > 25000) {
        comm = 0.15 * sale;
    }
    
    printf("commission is %f",comm);
    
    return 0;
}
```

in above code comm varriable cant be assigned without intializing to 0 at top. It doesnot throw error but its value is always 0 whenever i print it.  what can be the reason behind it ? Please if anybody could explain in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only "necessary" to initialize `comm` here for it to have a value if the user enters `25000` -- that's the only value that won't match any of the if statements, so won't assign a value to `comm`.

There'a also a potential issue if the user enters `X` or anything else that is not a number.  In that case `sale` will not be set, and will continue to be uninitialized, so any of the cases might trigger.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't really have to initialize the comm. And the code is fine, it should be working, maybe you have try a number too small (less than 10000) and that's why it's giving you 0. Try to double check that trying a bigger number :)

Answer (score 0):

Please complete `if else` statement. I mean include else statement too. So that, if control does find any proper condition, it can enter into else statement and initialize `comm` variables.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why C doesn't automatically initialize all local variables to zero is the "spirit of C", picking performance over safety unless told otherwise. The decision of whether to use maximum performance or maximum safety/defensive-programming is left to the programmer. Whereas other programming languages might not let you pick and always go with the safer option.

In your case no initialization is necessary. So if the code was explicitly setting the variable to zero first, then almost immediately after overwriting it with a value, then that would just be useless overhead code.

Similarly when using heap allocation, you have two options: `malloc` which is fast but doesn't perform zero-init, or `calloc` which is slower but does zero-init.